# How do I manually sign an Xcode UITests target?

Tags: xcode, xcuitest

Let's say I started a new project in Xcode and I disable `automatically manage signing`.

For a regular app, I'd generate:

1. A developer certificate
2. A development provisioning profile

Now, I wanted to do the same for the Tests and UITests target, to run them on a build server. What steps do I need to take and why?

Generating a developer provisioning profile for `{bundleID}UITests` doesn't work, that profile won't have the right entitlements (I think it doesn't have `get-task-allow`), Xcode will tell me. Do I need a wildcard provisioning profile for this?

Answer (score 0):

define a `UITests.xcconfig`, and pass it to `xcodebuild` with the `-xcconfig`

then inside the `UITests.xcconfig`:

```
CODE_SIGN_STYLE = Manual
CODE_SIGN_ENTITLEMENTS = MyApp/Myapp.entitlements
PROVISIONING_PROFILE_SPECIFIER = My Profile Name
CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY = iPhone Developer
```

This should be adequate for a simulated device. A real device will be more involved.